# Cannot connect to MongoDB: Exception authenticating MongoCredential

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, docker-compose

Using the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=testdb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

I try to connect to the MongoDB with the Kotlin driver:

```
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-kotlin-coroutine:4.10.1")
```

The connection code looks like this:

```
val client = MongoClient.create( "mongodb://root:rootpassword@localhost/testdb")
val database = client.getDatabase(databaseName = databaseName)
```

When running this I get the following error:

> com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='root', source='testdb', password=, mechanismProperties=}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify "testdb" as "defaultauthdb". MongoDB will look there for the specified credentials and can't find them. So, if you remove "/testdb" it should work.

See how the connection string is defined:

```
mongodb+srv://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

> username:password@.
>
> Optional. Authentication credentials.
>
> If specified, the client will attempt to authenticate the user to the
> authSource. If authSourceis unspecified, the client will attempt to authenticate the user to the defaultauthdb. And if the defaultauthdb is unspecified, to the admin database.

> /defaultauthdb.
>
> Optional. The authentication database to use if the connection string includes username:password@ authentication credentials but the authSource option is unspecified.
>
> If both authSource and defaultauthdb are unspecified, the client will attempt to authenticate the specified user to the admin database.

([Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/))